# Rails misreading table structure, how to make it aware of current strcuture

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have an existing database structure created outside or Rails. I've edited one of the db/migrate files to include all the proper columns (not sure if this is the right way to do it) yet in the app or even in the interactive console, Rails is malforming the SQL necessary to query the table, specifically it is missing the ID column.

```
SELECT `dvds`.* FROM `dvds` WHERE (`dvds`.`` >= 0) ORDER BY `dvds`.`` ASC LIMIT 1000
```

I've also ran rake db:create after editing the migrate file with the proper column names and types.

How do I tell Rails what the current structure is?

This happened to me before and I think I had to end up deleting all the migrate files and generating some files from scratch. I honestly can't remember what I did to fix it (should have written it down) but I'm sure there is a file I can edit to let Rails know the structure no?

Table schema:

```
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `studio` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `released` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `sound` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `versions` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `year` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `genre` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `aspect` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `upc` varchar(155) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `dvd_realease` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `directors` varchar(342) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `actors` varchar(342) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL
```

Migrate file:

```
class CreateDvds < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :dvds do |t|
        t.integer   :id
        t.string    :title
        t.string    :studio
        t.string    :released
        t.string    :status
        t.string    :sound
        t.string    :versions
        t.string    :price
        t.string    :rating
        t.string    :year
        t.string    :genre
        t.string    :aspect
        t.string    :upc
        t.timestamp :dvd_release
        t.timestamps
        t.string    :directors
        t.string    :actors

    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular example single table/model you do not have to "tell" Rails about the current structure of your database.  ActiveRecord will do this for you.  There is no file you update for this to work.

Ensure the dvds table has a primary key of "id" then all you need to do is have ActiveRecord class of Dvd.  Migrations are only required if you are updating the database in anyway (which it appears you are not).

This is a useful talk for using rails with legacy databases [slidesha.re/NbOo1](http://slidesha.re/NbOo1) He discusses a gem to allow rails to handle composite primary keys [bit.ly/MvEYk](http://bit.ly/MvEYk)

Comment: sorry, is that `rails script/generate model dvds` or `rails generate model Dvd` (which I've done but it says the model is already there and it is but empty and if I delete the model it gives me this error: Another migration is already named create_dvds: /.../db/migrate/20111116170531_create_dvds.rb)

Comment: The rails generator I've posted will generate a scaffold for your model.  So for example you would call your model Dvd and this will generate a migration to create table called dvds.

Can you post the DVD table schema and the DVD class & migration files?

Comment: Yes, when I ran `rails generate model Dvd` see above for what happened.

Comment: id column is added as a primary key by default.  Remove this from your migration and try again?

Comment: No joy, not even creating the scaffold from scratch with the fields in the generate command. This is very unnerving.

Comment: For this particular example single table/model you do not have to "tell" Rails about the current structure of your database.  ActiveRecord will do this for you.  There is no file you update for this to work.

Ensure the dvds table has a primary key of "id" then all you need to do is have ActiveRecord class of Dvd.  Migrations are only required if you are updating the database in anyway (which it appears you are not).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5232/discussion-between-charlie-quinn-and-kakubei)

Comment: You are correct Charlie! The table's primary key is not id, but rather a combination of id and title. After cleaning it up and making id the primary key it works! I wonder if there is a way of telling rails that the primary key is a combination of 2 columns, which is often a valid primary key?